# How I get junction Ids in veins-4.4? Which methods I must use?

Tags: omnet++, veins

I am using `veins4.4` and `sumo-0.25` and `omnet4.6`, I can't see `CommandGetJunctionIds()` or `GetIdsList()` methods in this version. These methods have used in older versions.
In `veins-4.4` , which methods I must use to get `junctionIds`?

Answer (score 0):

In Veins 4.4, the method to get junction IDs is called [`getJunctionIds`](https://github.com/sommer/veins/blob/veins-4.4/src/veins/modules/mobility/traci/TraCICommandInterface.h#L171). It is a member of the new command interface. See the [sample application](https://github.com/sommer/veins/blob/veins-4.4/src/veins/modules/application/traci/TraCIDemo11p.cc#L34) for how to use access this API efficiently.

Comment: Dear @Christoph Sommer, What method should I use instead of `traci->getJunctionPosition(...)` ? this method also was in older versions. i want to get position of Junctions...